# swing - changing the maximize button behavior

Tags: swing

I am trying to replace the maximize button in my (swing) screen. 
I want my frame to change it's size to my definition of max size and min size, 
without the window moving its position.
I tried the following ( and encountered a problem in all )
1. Frame.setMaximumSize, Frame.setMinimumSize. did actually nothing. 
2. tableFrame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
                    public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
then I resized the window 

did actually pretty well job in managing the sizes  - only that it jumped the screen to the top right corner every click . 
(And all I need is to resize the window size when maximize )
3. obviously adding window listener on componentResized doesnt do the job because when I change the sizes to my wanted size - it enters an infinite loop.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `Frame#setMaximizedBounds()`: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. this will set the correct size but it will jump the screen to the top left corner.

Comment: How can I make the screen stay on the same x.y location it was ?

Comment: Note that Rectangle (which you're giving as argument to setMaximizedBounds) lets you set the upper left corner to whatever you want. If you want to put it on the same xy location, first get the current xy location from Frame#getMaximizedBounds()#x and y, and then set them as the corner in the Rectangle that you give to setMaximizedBounds().

Comment: sorry, 
almost.. now it remebers only the initial location of the screen . if I move it, then it jumps back. to the original place. My last resort is to follow window move listener (or some listener like that ) and keep a static member of it

Comment: any better idea. (sorry for the different comments. pressing Enter is a habbit)

Comment: I can't think of any better idea for now. What you're trying to do is quite uncommon (I'm not aware of applications that keep their left corner in place when maximize is clicked - and I don't think the user expects that to happen either), so there's no easy ready way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I will explain . I am dealing with "every pixel counts" system. where the user has tons of information on many screens (stock systems). I thought of eliminating the jbutton that does resizes and reveals more data (which works great) and put its functionality in the maximize button. by that saving some more monitor space. Thanks for your assistance anyhow. :-)